# How to order data in an Ant Design V2.x table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using [Ant Design V2.X](https://2x.ant.design/components/table/) and I cannot update to a newer version. I inherited code and I am struggling to sort the data according to certain column. It should be ordered once, and not sorted dynamically.

This is what I have within the `return()` function of my React component:

```
<Table size="small"
       dataSource={this.props.Data}
       rowKey={(record) => (record.LedgerId * 100 + record.PositionId).toString()}
       pagination={false}
       showHeader={true}
>
```

I was assuming the `rowKey` would order my data according to the arrow-function, but this is not the case. **Can you all guide me how to solve this?**

#### Background info

Within the component, I have the following declaration:

```
export interface ViewTableProps {   
    selectedEntity: number,
    Data Interfaces.ViewEntry[],
}
```

and elsewhere

```
export interface ViewEntry {
    //Id: number,
    LedgerId: number,
    PositionId: number,
    Value: number,
    children: ViewEntry[]
}
```

#### Related and not-so related posts

- [Antd table - sort dosen't work with render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481071/antd-table-sort-dosent-work-with-render)
- [Can't sort Column in Ant Design Table in Gatsby site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479703/cant-sort-column-in-ant-design-table-in-gatsby-site)
- [Sort an antd (Ant Design) table that has selection enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879525/sort-an-antd-ant-design-table-that-has-selection-enabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add actual sorters to your individual columns, you'd need to write sort functions in the `sorter` property of your column definitions. If you want to sort the entire dataset by default, you could sort the dataSource before passing it to the table.

Column sort [from their docs](https://ant.design/components/table/):

```
{
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
  },
```

If you want a "default sort," you can just make a function to sort data outside the table;

```
const sortData = (data) => {
   // Call slice to create a new Array and prevent mutating it if it's stored in state
   return data.slice().sort((a, b) => a.myKey - b.myKey);
}

...

<Table size="small"
       dataSource={sortData(this.props.Data)}
       rowKey={(record) => (record.LedgerId * 100 + record.PositionId).toString()}
       pagination={false}
       showHeader={true}
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the massively helpful hint, I will try that. The trick I missed is to pre-sort the data.

Comment: Yeah, there's no built-in method that I know of. Hope it works out!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to order dates, I recommend this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

and add

```
{
 title: 'Date',
 dataIndex: 'date',
 key: "date",
 sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.date).unix() - moment(b.date).unix()
},
```

Comment: Add MomentJS for something that can be archived by in build JS Date is unnecessary and affects the overall bundle size. It adds a large chunk to the overall vender file.